# If loop printing the first error message instead of relevant message

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Section of assignment struggling with:
Login. The user should be prompted to enter a username and
password. A list of valid usernames and passwords are stored in a
text file called user.txt. Display an appropriate error message if the
user enters a username that is not listed in user.txt or enters a valid
username but not a valid password. The user should repeatedly be
asked to enter a valid username and password until they provide
appropriate credentials.

I have tried a while loop and an if loop however everytime the password is incorrect it prints "You have not entered a valid username.

```
usernames = [] # list for usernames
passwords = [] # list for passwords

with open("user.txt", "r") as file: # open user file in a read capacity as we are not writing to it

    for lines in file:
        temp = lines.strip() # Strip function is done first in order to remove newline character
        temp = temp.split(", ") # Split the username and password by the seperator of a comma and a space

        usernames.append(temp[0]) # By appending the index 0 we can add to usernames liste
        passwords.append(temp[1]) # By appending the index 1 we can add to passwords list

user_name = input("Please enter your username : ")
pass_word = input("Please enter your password : ")

if user_name not in usernames and pass_word not in passwords:
    print("You have not entered a valid username and password, please try again")
    user_name = input("Please enter your username : ")
    pass_word = input("Please enter your password : ")

elif user_name in usernames and pass_word not in passwords:
     print("You have not entered a valid password, please try again")
     user_name = input("Please enter your username : ")
     pass_word = input("Please enter your password : ")

elif user_name not in usernames and pass_word in passwords:
    print("You have not entered a valid username, please try again")
    user_name = input("Please enter your username : ")
    pass_word = input("Please enter your password : ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a while loop that runs as long as the credentials are incorrect. try this:

```
usernames = [] 
passwords = []

with open("user.txt", "r") as file: 
    for line in file:
        temp = line.strip()
        temp = temp.split(", ")
        usernames.append(temp[0])
        passwords.append(temp[1])

while True:
    user_name = input("Please enter your username: ")
    if user_name in usernames:
        pass_word = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if pass_word == passwords[usernames.index(user_name)]:
            print("Welcome, {}!".format(user_name))
            break 
        else:
            print("Incorrect password, please try again.")
    else:
        print("Invalid username, please try again.")
```

the user.txt file also should look like this:

```
alice, password1
bob, password2
charlie, password3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```py
# a bit more natural to use dict
passwords = {
    "Max": "qwerty",
    "Alex": "123456"
}

while True:
    # Check if the username exists
    user_name = input("Please enter your username: ")
    if user_name not in passwords:
        print("You have not entered a valid username, please try again")
        continue
    
    # Check if password is correct
    pass_word = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if passwords[user_name] != pass_word:
        print("Wrong password")
        continue
    
    else:
        print("Logged in")
        break  # or return something, if this is a function
```

Comment: We have not yet been taught about dictionaries but will also try this approach and learn something new